# Multi threaded programs in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am about to write my first multi threaded Java application. The task basically is to create sales report for a set of products; the products and the inputs to the report generator class are completely independent.

I believe we can create multiple threads (I would like to control the number of threads to create from a properties files based on number of CPUs in the target machine). to use them generate reports asynchronously. Currently this is what I do in my single threaded program.

I wish Java gurus give me some inputs on the design. Thanks in advance.

Structure of Report Generator class

```
public class SalesReportGenerator
{
    //Variables

    public Report prepareReport(Product prod){
        //Implementation
    }

    //Helper methods used by SalesReportGenerator.prepareReport
}
```

My current implementation which I would like to perform in a multi threaded approach.

```
public class ReportCreater
{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        ListProducts listProd = new ListProducts(); //Getting product list
        ArrayList products =  listProd.getProductAsArrayList(); //To store list of products

        ArrayList reports = new ArrayList(); //To store reports
        SalesReportGenerator salesGen = new SalesReportGenerator();

        Report tempReport = null;

        for (int i;i<products.size() ;i++ )
        {
            tempReport = salesGen.prepareReport(products.get(i));
            reports.add(tempReport);

        }
        //At this point I will have reports for all the producst 
        //which I can use for processing, further reporting/saving.
    }
}
```

I would like to know what is the best way to first create a set of threads and make them pick a product and generate report.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a class that creates a thread pool and distribute the report generation tasks among them. Java already provides such a class. It is called [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). You define a task as a `Runnable` and pass it to an object of `ExecutorService`. When you create this object, you should specify the size of the thread pool. If the tasks are CPU intensive, you might want to limit this size to `NumberOfProcessors + 1`. (See [this example](http://www.javadb.com/get-number-of-available-processors) on how to determine the value of `NumberOfProcessors`). You submit as many tasks as you want to this object and it will manage how they get executed by the available threads. There are [many tutorials](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20051126/JavaMultithreading_Tutorial_Part4.html) on the web that [shows you how to use this class](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/executorservice).

Comment: Thanks a lot Vijay. I shall try it out immediately.